# I am getting NoSuchMethodeError

Tags: android

I am working with a quiz app which has no errors when it's launched in marshmallow, but when I try to launch my app in lollipop I'm getting the error which I have given below:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method
getContext()Landroid/content/Context; in class
Lcom/javaquiz/asriq/asr/com/aseeriumiq/Fragments/CourseFragment; or
its super classes (declaration of
'com.javaquiz.asriq.asr.com.aseeriumiq.Fragments.CourseFragment'
appears in
/data/data/com.javaquiz.asriq.asr.com.aseeriumiq/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `getActivity()` to acquire a Context.

[`getContext()` does not exist in the Lollipop API. It was added with Marshmallow](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes.html)

If you were using Support Fragments, you would not have that problem as `getContext()` is not implemented on them.

Comment: Okay. Let me replace getContext() to getActivity() and will come back. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Replace getContext() with getActivity().

Comment: Yes will do. Thank you.